# matrix Python собрать значения по диагонали

Tags: python-3.x, матрицы

Нужно вывести значения пo диагонали из матрицы Python. Начальная точка - самая верхнее левое значение. Надо получить все значения по диагонали. При со столкновением со "стеной", надо "оттолкнуться" и пойти по другой диагонали. И так, пока не вернемся в исходную точку. Как это сделать! Помогите, пожалуйста!
Например, матрица:

```
 1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 14
```

результат должен быть следующий: `1 7 13 9 5 9 13 7 1`

Comment: Поскольку это явно учебное задание, вы должны хоть что-то сами попытаться, прежде чем просить помощь зала

Answer (score 1):

Всегда пожалуйста.

```
from math import gcd


def func(x, y):
    global n, m
    return y * m + x + 1


def get_indexes(x, y):
    global n, m, h, w
    x, y = x % w, y % h
    new_x, new_y = x, y
    if x >= m - 1: new_x = w - x
    if y >= n - 1: new_y = h - y
    return new_x, new_y


n, m = 3, 5 #size input
h, w = 2 * n - 2, 2 * m - 2

ans = []
for i in range(h * w // gcd(h, w) + 1):
    x, y = get_indexes(i, i)
    ans.append(func(x, y))

print(' '.join(map(str, ans))) #1 7 13 9 5 9 13 7 1
```

Правда мое решение не работает для полей, в которых хотя бы одна сторона равна единице, но разбор этого случая я оставлю вам.